# Inexplicable base bias

Tags: transistors, inverting-amplifier

I have a common emitter amplifier on my breadboard (the same circuit as the image) with the following values: C = .01uF, R1 = R2=15k, RL = 5k, RE = 1k, and Vcc= 10v.

The reason I have R1= R2 is I want VB = 5V. (Base voltage)

The reason I have RL=5k and RE= 1k is i want the gain to be -5.

However, I measured the voltage at the base and got 2.7 ish volts instead.  When I removed the tranaistor, the voltage value quickly went to 5v.

Also, the voltage output showed the gain was less than 1.

I am trying to understand how the transistor can affect the base voltage value so much and why the gain isnt consistent with the formula -RL/RE.[image]

Comment: I do not have a C2 by the way.

Comment: Set V_E and R_E according to the current you want. Then V_B follows. V_B=5V won't work given the other constraints on your circuit (VCC and R_L/R_E).

Comment: You've biased your transistor into saturation. It won't amplify in that state.

Comment: @Felthry. I guess i have to check the datasheet but this means i want R2 to be less such that VB is lower? But what if I do want the input impedance to be 7.5k ?  Guess i just have to increase R1?

Comment: Reducing \$R_E\$ might help as well.

Comment: @Felthry. What if I do want to have the output impedance of 5k while the gain is -5 though? That pretty much fixes RL and RE...

Comment: Then you can't have \$V_B = 5 V\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing \$ R_C = 5 R_E \$ is a good start. That should give a gain nearly -5.

You want the collector voltage to have room to swing up and down in a linear amplifier. Vc should be able to swing up (to Vcc), and swing down (to Vb). This means that collector current much higher than 0.8 mA is too much when Rc=5k, Re=1k.
With 0.8mA, collector will idle at 6V. Emitter will be at 0.8V, and base will be about 0.7V higher (at 1.5V).
So choose R1 and R2 to bias the base at close to 1.5V. This will require care, because any error will amplify by 5 at the collector.

Comment: Thank you. In terms of voltage swing of the output, the smaller the base voltage bias, the more room i have.  Knowing that i want the input impedance to be about 5k, i would just fix my R2 a little over and 5k and adjust R1 such that Id  and Ie are reasonable (which are pretty much the same). Is there any downside to making R1 arbitrarily huge? I dont see any downside to making R1 huge.

Comment: Your plan making R2 a little over 5k is a good start. Choose a standard value, perhaps 5.6k or 6.8k. Then calculate R1 to get base voltage = 1.5V. Choosing large values for R1, R2 is not good - transistor **Hfe variations** are often huge, and will influence the bias point if this is a design to be replicated. I wouldn't try this design for voltage gain much larger than 5. That's where the emitter bypass capacitor can help you do low DC gain combined with high AC gain.

Comment: Thank you again. Could you elaborate how you chose .8mA? I see that i certainly cannot let Ic become 10/6mA because that would put it above 10V (more than my Vcc). Is the idea to maximize the range of values available for Vout by making VC as big and VE as small as possible? Then it's just a matter of making VE as close to ground as possible? I feel like im missing something here

Comment: Since Rc dominates over Re, I start with a static **Ic** that brings **Vc** to half the supply voltage. That'd be 1mA. That'd work OK but leaves no room for **Ve** which would be 1V. **Vc** signal can swing about 3V peak. A little less **Ic** allows more swing.

Comment: Thank you again. I see that you want the Vc to be centered at around half the supply voltage, which leads to 1mA.  You say that you want to leave more room for Ve and so you want the current to be less than 1mA? But then Ve would be even more limited (Ic=1mA => Ve=1V vs Ic=.8mA => Ve= .8V)

Comment: With **Ic** =0.8mA, collector current can swing between 0mA - 1.6mA at signal peaks. This would result in collector voltage swinging between +10V and +2V. When collector is at +2V, emitter is at +1.6V (very near saturation). This gives a peak swing of +/- 4V. A larger signal gets clipped at both top and bottom peaks. That's close to optimum if your signal is symmetric, like audio.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set bias current to 4.3V/1k = 4.3mA, which would drop 21.5V across the collector resistor.

Your transistor is saturating and loading the base resistor divider.

---

Edit:

The circuit as far as the base voltage looks like the below, because the transistor is saturated and has likely < 0.1V Vce.

The base current flows directly into the emitter resistor with one diode drop since R4 (your load resistor) is already contributing as much current through the transistor collector as it can.

Simulation with the diode shows the voltage at about 2.5V, which is close to your measurement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmEUU0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What does it mean to load the base resistor divider though? Does it mean the base is drawing a lot of current through R1? ( Sorry, im just not familiar with the term 'loading the base resistor.'

Comment: When the transistor is in the active region the base current is a small part of the emitter current, maybe 1/300 for a good transistor. Once you saturate the transistor  all the additional emitter current comes from the base, like a diode between base and emitter (with the load resistor effectively connected to the emitter). See above edit.

Comment: Your base divider has a Thevenin equivalent of a 5V source with 7.5K in series, so the 1K resistor loads it down something fierce.

Answer (score 3):

> What if I do want to have the output impedance of 5k while the gain is
>   -5 though? That pretty much fixes RL and RE...

Elsewhere, you write in your question that \$V_\text{CC}=10\:\text{V}\$. If you want \$A_\text{V}=5\$ then you don't want an AC-grounded emitter. You want something different. One of these two topologies:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcH5Hx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They do the same thing. It's just that you need to compute different values for the two emitter leg resistors, is all. Otherwise, they are equivalent. (It would be better still if you used a bootstrapped design because the input impedance would be much higher, which is usually considered a good thing. But that is for another day.)

With \$V_\text{CC}=10\:\text{V}\$, I'd reserve about \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{MIN}}=2\:\text{V}\$ and set \$V_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}=1.5\:\text{V}\$. This leaves about \$10\:\text{V}-1.5\:\text{V}-2\:\text{V}=7.5\:\text{V}\$ for the collector range.

Of that remaining range for the collector, there is another consideration to worry about. You don't actually want the collector current to vary from large numbers down to zero, if possible. So you need to reserve something for the high-end collector voltage as a margin of sorts. So let's reserve out \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ at the top. So this means the collector voltage will be \$3.5\:\text{V} \le V_\text{C}\le 7.5\:\text{V}\$, giving \$4\:\text{V}\$ as the peak-to-peak swing. This means \$\pm 2\:\text{V}\$ at the output. With \$A_\text{V}=5\$, this means the input voltage can be \$\pm 400 \:\text{mV}\$.

The collector's voltage margin on the topside is helpful. It means \$4.9\le A_v\le 5.04\$, with peak to peak gain variation at \$.14\$ and the distortion factor well below 1%. Note the asymmetry, though? That comes from only reserving \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ at the top. Reserving more would help, but it has its price too. So this is an acceptable compromise. Different people would choose differently. But this is an example and overthinking would muddle the rest I'm trying to say. So leave it here.

The rest is easy. Let's select \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}=\frac{3.5\:\text{V}+7.5\:\text{V}}{2}=5.5\:\text{V}\$. So \$I_\text{Q}=\frac{10\:\text{V}-5.5\:\text{V}}{5\:\text{k}\Omega}=900\:\mu\text{A}\$. Therefore \$r_{e_\text{Q}}=\frac{k\: T}{q\:I_\text{Q}}\approx 28.55\:\Omega\$. This means that \$R_{\text{E}\left(\text{AC}\right)}=\frac{5\:\text{k}\Omega}{5}-r_{e_\text{Q}}\approx 971\:\Omega\$ and that \$R_{\text{E}\left(\text{DC}\right)}=\frac{1.5\:\text{V}}{900\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 1.667\:\text{k}\Omega\$. From there, you get \$R_{\text{E}\left(\text{AC}\right)'}\approx 2328\:\Omega\$ and \$R_{\text{E}\left(\text{DC}\right)'}\approx 696\:\Omega\$.

Using nearby standard values, we find these values to be acceptably close:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqgn2q.png)</sup>

To keep the base dividers relatively "stiff," they should have about \$\frac1{10}\$th of the quiescent collector current: or about \$90\:\mu\text{A}\$. I'd estimate about \$V_{\text{BE}_\text{Q}}\approx 670\:\text{mV}\$, so \$V_{\text{B}_\text{Q}}\approx 2.17\:\text{V}\$. With as little as \$\beta=100\$ I figure the base current to be no worse than \$9\:\mu\text{A}\$. So, from there I can work out that \$R_1=\frac{10\:\text{V}-2.17\:\text{V}}{90\:\mu\text{A}+9\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 79\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=\frac{2.17\:\text{V}}{90\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 24\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

Again, with 5% tolerance standard values I now have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8wfiv.png)</sup>

Feel free to try and simulate these. They should produce reasonable results and a gain close to what you wanted to see. (I haven't done it yet, but I'm confident they will simulate close to the above predictions.) If you build them, they should also work reasonably close to the design goal.